# java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://localhost:9000/home/hduser/sqoop/lib/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar

Tags: java, hadoop, sqoop

I am basically a mysql guy and new in hadoop and trying to import one mysql table on my hadoop system by sqoop and using below command but getting error. I search on net but not getting any possible solution.

I will be very thankful for your support.

[hduser@localhost ~]$ sqoop-import --connect jdbc:mysql://192.168.12.172:3306/test --username root -P --table users_log

Error:
15/02/25 16:26:40 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://localhost:9000/home/hduser/sqoop/lib/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar

Even This file exist on same path, details are below-

```
[hduser@localhost ~]$ ls -lh /home/hduser/sqoop/lib/
total 5.1M
-rwxr-xr-x 1 hduser hadoop 220K Aug  1  2014 ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 hduser hadoop  36K Aug  1  2014 ant-eclipse-1.0-jvm1.2.jar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 hduser hadoop 392K Aug  1  2014 avro-1.7.5.jar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 hduser hadoop 167K Aug  1  2014 avro-mapred-1.7.5-hadoop2.jar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 hduser hadoop 236K Aug  1  2014 commons-compress-1.4.1.jar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 hduser hadoop 107K Aug  1  2014 commons-io-1.4.jar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 hduser hadoop 691K Aug  1  2014 hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 hduser hadoop 227K Aug  1  2014 jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 hduser hadoop 763K Aug  1  2014 jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 hduser hadoop 932K Mar 11  2014 mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 hduser hadoop  29K Aug  1  2014 paranamer-2.3.jar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 hduser hadoop 1.2M Aug  1  2014 snappy-java-1.0.5.jar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 hduser hadoop  93K Aug  1  2014 xz-1.0.jar
```

Comment: What I did was actually go into hue and create the necessary folders and uploaded the necessary files. It stopped complaining afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hdfs://localhost:9000/ is hadoop hdfs address.
you can change property in your app or upload your jar on hdfs.

You display ls command of your linux file system but hdfs://localhost:9000/  is addres of hadoop hdfs file system.

Comment: I am not using any application, I am just importing a table by sqoop utility from my linux system....also hadoop shows this path itself in this way as per my assumption like hdfs://localhost:9000/

Comment: http://my.safaribooksonline.com/9781849517300/ch09s07_html?iid=2013-04-blog-hadoop-book-9781849517300-SBOBlog

Comment: Set you home path. or "hdfs dfs -put /home/hduser/sqoop   hdfs://localhost:9000/home/hduser/sqoop"

Comment: getting error "put: `hdfs://localhost:9000/home/hduser/sqoop'": No such file or directory

Comment: Actually hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar file exist at path /home/hduser/sqoop/lib/ but when I am checking by hdfs dfs -ls hdfs://localhost:9000/ it is showing at hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hduser/sqoop/lib/....why this is showing user dir instead of home for hdfs...any clue/help.

Comment: try hdfs dfs -put /home/hduser/sqoop hdfs://localhost:9000/home/hduser/sqoop

Comment: Check installation http://my.safaribooksonline.com/9781849517300/ch09s07_html?iid=2013-04-blog-hadoop-book-9781849517300-SBOBlog

Comment: hdfs dfs -mkdir hdfs://localhost:9000/home/

Comment: hdfs dfs -put /home/hduser/sqoop hdfs://localhost:9000/home/hduser/sqoop..........actually there is no dir "home" at my hdfs path instead there was "user" other path is same...I don't know why this is...

Comment: create directory using "hdfs dfs -mkdir hdfs://localhost:9000/home/ "

Comment: I used following command: hdfs dfs -mv hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hduser/sqoop hdfs://localhost:9000/home/hduser/sqoop...now not getting earlier error but getting new error "java.lang.Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class users_log not found" where users_log is my table name. any help please..

Comment: What out put of $echo $SQOOP_HOME?

Comment: try to install /opt directory

Comment: hadoop/hive/sqoop all are in /home/hduser/....may you describe little bit for /opt..

Comment: /opt is director at root level

Comment: Created but still getting same issue...not able to understand use of /opt.I am using following sqoop command : "sqoop-import --connect jdbc:mysql://192.168.12.172:3306/test --username root -P --table users_log"

Comment: Thanks OP, you are right it was hdfs permission issue after putting my related directory on hdfs it is working fine with my existing directory.

Comment: Hi, i have similiar problem, could you check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62532940/kafka-connector-to-hdfs-java-io-filenotfoundexception-file-does-not-exist . thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please execute below commands which will resolve your problem. It will copy your files in HDFS system.

hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal /opt/hadoop/sqoop-1.4.6 hdfs://localhost:9000/opt/hadoop/sqoop-1.4.6

hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal /opt/hadoop/sqoop-1.4.6/lib hdfs://localhost:9000/opt/hadoop/sqoop-1.4.6/lib

Note : please treat below curly braces inline section as one line

{hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal /opt/hadoop/sqoop-1.4.6/sqoop-1.4.6.jar hdfs://localhost:9000/opt/hadoop/sqoop-1.4.6/sqoop-1.4.6.jar}

Similarly copy any file which is not able to get by HDFS system.

Note : In above command /opt/hadoop/sqoop-1.4.6 is my system sqoop installation location

Thanks, Iqubal Mustafa Kaki