# sqoop error on import

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

On running the below command, I get an error -

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/hadoopguide --table widgets -m 1
```

I dont know why it's looking for the avro jar file in HDFS.

`SQOOP_HADOOP_HOME` and `SQOOP_MAPRED_HOME` are set to Hadoop directory.
I am using Hadoop 2.6.0 and sqoop version 1.4.5

```
15/11/12 14:56:49 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
15/11/12 14:56:49 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Cleaning up the staging area file:/tmp/hadoop-pranay/mapred/staging/pranay1505087555/.staging/job_local1505087555_0001
15/11/12 14:56:49 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://127.0.0.1:54310/home/<some id>/sqoop-1.4.5.bin__hadoop-2.0.4-alpha/lib/avro-1.7.5.jar
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1122)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1114)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
```

Comment: Getting Same error

Answer (score 0):

make sure your lib folder contains all the below jars.

```
[root@sandbox lib]# pwd
/usr/hdp/current/sqoop-client/lib
[root@sandbox lib]# ls -l
total 6832
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  224135 2015-03-31 21:03 ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   36427 2015-03-31 21:03 ant-eclipse-1.0-jvm1.2.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  400090 2015-03-31 21:03 avro-1.7.5.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  170228 2015-03-31 21:03 avro-mapred-1.7.5-hadoop2.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  241259 2015-03-31 21:03 commons-compress-1.4.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  108990 2015-03-31 21:03 commons-io-1.4.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  706015 2015-03-31 21:03 hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  229445 2015-03-31 21:03 jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  770013 2015-03-31 21:03 jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      40 2015-04-30 08:50 mysql-connector-java.jar -> /usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2714189 2015-10-17 03:09 ojdbc6.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   29532 2015-03-31 21:03 paranamer-2.3.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1245776 2015-03-31 21:03 snappy-java-1.0.5.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   94608 2015-03-31 21:03 xz-1.0.jar
```

Also check your **hdfs permissions..** 

which user you are running Sqoop with.. and which user has permissions on the folder.

This SO question has more info.. 
[java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://localhost:9000/home/hduser/sqoop/lib/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28717193/java-io-filenotfoundexception-file-does-not-exist-hdfs-localhost9000-home-h)

Answer (score 0):

1. Set HADOOP_HOME and SQOOP_HOME
2. Create same $SQOOP_HOME/lib directory in hdfs.

   `hdfs dfs -mkdir -p $SQOOP_HOME/lib`

   Use full path instead of $SQOOP_HOME if not working
3. Copy all files present in $SQOOP_HOME/lib to $SQOOP_HOME/lib in hdfs.

   `hdfs dfs -put $SQOOP_HOME/lib /$SQOOP_HOME/lib`

Download and copy missing jars to both local and hdfs $SQOOP_HOME/lib directory